# JQL get hours logged per person per day

Tags: jira, jql

Hi guys so I am trying to make my life a bit easier and figure out how to get the values logged against different tasks by the same person in 1 day so I can basically get the sum of their hours logged in total.  Currently I can do this via the browser filter option using:

`worklogAuthor = currentUser() AND worklogDate = "2019/01/30"`

The problem is it returns entire tasks not just the hours so I need to click through each task and then get the number against the work log.  Is there a way I could limit the fields being returned so I just see the work logged and maybe the task id?  I see that there is some documentation out there to do that but I haven't been able to get it quite right yet.

Comment: use scriptrunner to aggregate :
https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_aggregateexpression

Comment: is this default out of the box or do i need to add a plugin? I am having trouble to get this to work right it's unable to find many of the things

Comment: that's a paid plugin , no out-of-the-box solution here as far as i know.

Comment: if anyone has something for a free solution of the of box would love some feedback.  As of now I have come to the conclusion the best I can do is my above example.  At this point you must click through all of the logged tasks and sum them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Given that it has been 2+ years, I hope you have since found another approach. The issue you are bumping into is simply that the Advanced Search will only return a list of tasks, you can't modify that "select". What I would recommend is leveraging either the reporting or dashboarding functionality. The 2 widgets that I would recommend would be either Issue Statistics, or Workload Pie Chart. Worst case scenario, you can always dump the data out to a csv or retrieve from an API and aggregate your data that way as well.